Spectrum of discrete Schrödinger operator with single binary defect
I am considering the following simple Schroedinger operator $H:\ell^{2}\left(\mathbb{Z}\right) \to \ell^{2}\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)$ given by:
\begin{align*}
\left(H\psi\right)\left(n\right) =\ &
\psi\left(n - 1\right) + \psi\left(n - 1\right) +
A\mathbf{1}_{\left\{0\right\}}\left(n\right) \psi\left(n\right)
\\[1mm] & \forall\ \psi \in \ell^{2}\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)\quad \mbox{and} \quad n \in \mathbb{Z},
\end{align*}
for some $A \geq 0$ with
$\mathbf{1}_{\left\{0\right\}}$ being the indicator function of $\left\{0\right\}$.

I think of this operator as the
free Laplacian plus a potential supported on a single defect at $0\in \mathbb{Z}$.
If $A=0$, then this is just the free Laplacian and the spectrum is known to be $\left[-2,2\right]$.
However, the case when $A > 2$ seems like it should already be known in the literature under some name unfamiliar to me.
Does anyone have any reference or solution to
what $\mbox{spec}\left(H\right)$ should be ?. Or is it more complicated then it seems ?.


localization - delocalization transition?

@user619894 Are you suggesting this is something I should look at? It's probably because I don't know about this, but I don't see how this applies to this question.

yes, the starting point of localization, or depinning is usually a single defect, so I assume there is some treatment of the problem

@user619894 Do you know of any mathematical papers or books where this is laid out? I haven't found a simple introduction to this.

the continuum version is treated in many qm books. look for "delta function potential". I suppose the discretization follows.

You can build intuition by approaching the problem as a physicist and finding formal eigenvectors. From induction all eigenvectors are of the form:
$$
\psi_n=\begin{cases}
\psi_-^+q^n+\psi_-^-q^{-n} & n\leq 0\\
\psi_+^+q^n+\psi_+^-q^{-n} & n\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
with eigenvalue:
$$
E=q+q^{-1}
$$
Using parity you can further restrict your attention to even and odd states:
$$
\psi_n=\begin{cases}
\psi^-q^n+\psi^+q^{-n} & n\leq 0\\
\psi^+q^n+\psi^-q^{-n} & n\geq 0
\end{cases} \\
\psi_n=\begin{cases}
-\psi^-q^n-\psi^+q^{-n} & n\leq 0\\
\psi^+q^n+\psi^-q^{-n} & n\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
The eigenvector equation at $n=0$ and consistency at $n=0$ further restrict the possible solutions to:
$$
\psi_n\propto\text{sgn}(n)(q^n-q^{-n})
$$
in the odd case, and to:
$$
\psi_n\propto (q^{-1}-q+A)q^{|n|}-(q-q^{-1}+A)q^{-|n|}
$$
in the even case.
There are now two cases to consider depending on the modulus of $q$. If $|q|\neq1$ assume with no loss of generality by replacing by $1/q$ that $|q|>1$. To avoid the exponential divergence, the prefactor of $q^{|n|}$ must vanish. You have a legitimate eigenvector (in $l^2$). Physically, it is a localized bound state given by the equation:
$$
q-q^{-1}=A \\
E=\text{sgn}(A)\sqrt{4+A^2}
$$
You have delocalized unbound states for unimodular $|q|=1$. As usual, the sequence is not an eigenvector as it does not lie in $l^2$.
Therefore for $A\neq0$, you still have the continuous band spectrum $[-2,2]$ and isolated eigenvalue:
$$
E_0=\text{sgn}(A)\sqrt{4+A^2}
$$
When viewing from the $A\to0$ limit, the unbound states smoothly deform and the bound state suddenly detaches from the edge of the band.
More rigorously, you can prove without much theory by looking at where the resolvent $R(E) = (H-E)^{-1}$ is defined. For this, it is best to revert to the $z\in\mathbb U$ transform (or Fourier with $z=e^{ik}$):
$$
\hat \psi(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\psi_n z^n \\
\psi_n = \frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1} \hat\psi(z)\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}
$$
The resolvent amounts to solving:
$$
(H-E)\psi = \phi\\
\left(z+z^{-1}-E\right)\hat\psi(z) +A\psi_0 = \hat\phi(z)
$$
If $E\not\in[-2,2]$, then you can divide:
$$
\hat\psi(z) = \frac{\hat\phi(z)}{z+z^{-1}-E}-\frac{A\psi_0}{z+z^{-1}-E}
$$
and solve for:
$$
\left(1+\frac1{2\pi i}\oint\frac A{z+z^{-1}-E}\frac{dz}z\right)\psi_0 = \frac1{2\pi i}\oint\frac{\hat\phi(z)}{z+z^{-1}-E}\frac{dz}z
$$
The RHS is well defined since $\hat\phi\in L^2$, and you can compute the LHS's integral by residues to get:
$$
\left(1-\frac A{\sqrt{E^2-4}}\right)\psi_0 = \frac1{2\pi i}\oint\frac{\hat\phi(z)}{z+z^{-1}-E}\frac{dz}z
$$
with the square root being unambiguously defined by the branch where $\sqrt{E^2-4}\sim E$ for $E\to\infty$ and a branch cut along $(-2,2)$. Therefore, for $E\neq E_0$, you can divide by the prefactor and solve for $\psi_0$. Thus the resolvent is well defined for all $E$ not in the previously identified spectrum. You can check that it is bounded by triangular inequality:
$$
\|R(E)\|\leq \frac1{d(E,[-2,2])}\left(1+\frac1{2\pi}\left|\frac1A-\frac1{\sqrt{E^2-4}}\right|^{-1}\left\|\frac1{z+z^{-1}-E}\right\|_2\right)
$$
As expected, the bound diverge as $E$ gets close to the spectrum. To finish up rigorously, you just need to verify that $(-2,2)$ is indeed in the spectrum. They are not eigenvalues, but you can check that for $E\in[-2,2]$, $H-E$ is not surjective.

Thank you very much for your answer. Is there somewhere you know where the relation between $\psi_n$ and the integral of the Fourier transform is discussed? I didn't really get that part.

It’s just your usual Fourier series expansion, the isometry between $l^2$ and $L^2(\mathbb U)$ (i.e. $L^2(\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z)$):$$\hat \psi(k) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\psi_n e^{ikn} \
\psi_n = \int_0^{2\pi} \hat\psi(k)\frac{dk}{2\pi}$$It’s just more convenient for computations to think in terms of $z$ transform to actually compute the integrals
